# Issue with QCA (Qt C++ Encryption Library) run on windows 7

Tags: c++, qt, encryption

I am using Qt 4.8.1, MinGW compiler and Qt Creator, all on windows 7. I want to add an encryption/ decryption library to my project. After searching the web for couple days I found [QCA](http://delta.affinix.com/qca/). Fortunately I found a [pre-built](http://delta.affinix.com/download/qca/2.0/qca-2.0.1-mingw.zip) version using the same C++ compiler I am using, and a pre-built version of the needed [plugins](http://delta.affinix.com/download/qca/2.0/qca-2.0-plugins-latest-mingw.zip). 
I followed the [instructions](http://www.essentialunix.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=48%3aqcatutorial&catid=34%3aqttutorials&Itemid=53) to add the QCA library to my project. I used a code like this to encrypt using AES:

```
QCA::Initializer init = QCA::Initializer();

//Here where the execution stops
QCA::SymmetricKey key = QCA::SymmetricKey(16);

QCA::InitializationVector iv = QCA::InitializationVector(16);

QCA::Cipher cipher = QCA::Cipher(QString("aes128"), QCA::Cipher::CBC,
                                 QCA::Cipher::DefaultPadding, QCA::Encode,
                                 key, iv);

if (!QCA::isSupported("aes128-cbc-pkcs7"))
{
    qDebug() << "AES128 is not supported";
    return;
}
```

The code compiles just fine but when I run the application stops with unknown reason.

I really got tired from this bug, if anybody can help it will be very very very appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried attaching a debugger to find out why?

Comment: Yes I have and while debugging and when I reach the line I mentioned in the question I get a message box that says: "The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the Operating System. Signal name: SIGSEGV Signal meaning: Segmentation fault".
And the application output says: "(Internal error: pc 0x201 in read in psymtab, but not in symtab.)". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately, that indicated a gdb bug, so unless you can find or compile an update you might not be able to debug. Are you using the latest ones? (Currently gcc 4.7.0.1 and gdb 7.5.1.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### For future programmers that might get stuck on this

QCA loads the plugins at runtime, so even if it compiles fine, if the plugin is not in a searchable folder, it won't load.

You can check if that's the problem by calling `qDebug() << QCA::supportedFeatures();`. If the plugins are **not** being loaded, you'll get something like:

```
("random", "md5", "sha1", "keystorelist")
```

You should be able to see the folders QCA is looking up by calling:

```
qDebug("%s", QCA::pluginDiagnosticText().toUtf8().constData());
```

Apparently, plugins must be placed in a subdirectory called `crypto` in the libs root directory.

You can check for all the paths where Qt looks for libraries using:

```
qDebug() << QCoreApplication::instance()->libraryPaths();
```

This documentation might have some useful information: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpluginloader.html